# How to connect naked camera from mobile phone to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, camera

Okay, guys. I have this 3 cameras(middle from the iPhone 6s, 2 at the side I found, and I think there are from modern phone). **I need some information how to connect Arduino Uno to them.** I know c/c++, assembler, but noob in microcontrollers, if this knowledge can come useful.[image]

Comment: No chance. Sorry. Think again.

Comment: About fingerprint sensor, but the answer is fitting also this question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/71753/can-i-connect-a-android-phone-fingerprint-scanner-to-arduino-or-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: sounds like a call, thx

Comment: I don't think an UNO could do anything useful with any of those cameras

Comment: Can u offer something else?

Comment: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-face-recognition-arduino-ide/

Comment: This is a demo code with a proximity sensor on how to Trigger the camera of your cell Phone by Arduino. You can make Ultrasound Motion sensor or PIR sensor to work as a Motion sensing anti theft Camera system. * It's just an Idea , The Sky is the Limit */
int trig = 13;
void setup() { pinMode(trig,OUTPUT); Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
}
void loop() // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
{ int sensorValue = analogRead(A0); // read the input on analog pin 0: Serial.println(sensorValue); // print out the value you read: delay(1); /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either a memory extension for your UNO - projects like Arducam did this way back 2016 and then used an OV2640 module. If you want to develop something yourself these are the steps (hurdles) to take:

- Get a datasheet of the camera
- Design a circuit including

  - plug for Camera and a
  - memory module (min 512Kb)
- Attach it to the UNO
- Write a library/function module (see datasheet for details) and
- bring it to life

My tip save ca. two years of your life and get for 6-8$ an ESP32cam
This will cost you enough of your time, but be much more rewarding